# Method for building lightweight, cross-platform, text editor

Tags: graphics, air, gtk, shoes, xulrunner

I'm planning to build a simple, lightweight text editor that combines a great look with keyboard focused input.

I want to have a lot of control over things like antialiasing and all the graphics in general, but I don't care about having a whole library of widgets. Almost the entire UI will be text-based and in the main canvas/window of the app.

- Toolkits like GTK and Qt seem like overkill - tons of widgets I don't need and a complex codebase.
- Titanium, AIR, and XULRunner are even bigger in some ways - dev would be quick, but that's not exactly the lightweight approach.
- Shoes seemed like a nearly perfect fit, but it's a little too small and doesn't support enough events (e.g. no window resize).

What do you think, should I just build it on Cairo/Pango or another graphics library and roll the platform specific stuff myself? I'd rather use a framework of some kind.

Basically all I want is:

- good event handling
- windowing
- menus
- drawing with really great type rendering choices

I would love to build this cross-platform from the start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you use  just Cairo/Pango you still need windows on the screen.

The simplest combination would be cairo + pango + GDK (the windowing part of GTK+)
however even in that case you have no menus, and constructing menus with pure Cairo
would be a tough (but not impossible) accomplishment.

If you insist on lightweight and crossplatform then check the following

- [Fast Light Toolkit](http://www.fltk.org/)
- [Fox Toolkit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FOX_toolkit)
- [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/) (goes great with Python)

Comment: Thanks. wxWidgets looks like a great choice. wxRuby feels like a more complicated, more mature version of Shoes, which is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

[Scintilla](http://www.scintilla.org/) is a cross-platfrom source code editing component (based on GTK+) with excellent support for syntax highlighting, code folding, text zooming, and of course all the usual text editing functions; it should be an excellent foundation for a text editor.